# Каждое обращение к php файлу - это новая сессия битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Записываю данные в сессию в файле `class.php` в компоненте, когда пытаюсь их получить в другой функции в этом же классе - оказывается ничего нет.

**Каждое обращение к php файлу - это новая сессия битрикс?**

**Получается у меня файл class.php открывается несколько раз?****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте как устроены сессии в php, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php, так как по описанию проблемы, кажется, что вы не так все используете

И прямо отвечаю на ваш вопрос - нет.